# how to clear renderer after calling SDL_RenderPresent?

Tags: sdl-2

I create a texture for a renderer, after calling SDL_RenderPresent for seconds, I want to clear it on the screen?
I use SDL_RenderClear, but not worked.

```
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
            SDL_Delay(5000);
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SDL_RenderPresent()` updates the screen, you need to call it again after the `SDL_RenderClear()` call.

Taken from [the remarks section](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderPresent):

> SDL's rendering functions operate on a backbuffer; that is, calling a
>   rendering function such as SDL_RenderDrawLine() does not directly put
>   a line on the screen, but rather updates the backbuffer. As such, you
>   compose your entire scene and present the composed backbuffer to the
>   screen as a complete picture.

The `SDL_RenderClear()` call you have made is operating on that back buffer.